# Website automatically changing URL to dev/production server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, netbeans

I have inherited a webapp that I am trying to get set up locally on my work PC with Xampp, Codeigniter & Netbeans.

I have the project imported successfully into netbeans and can hit the run button and it opens in the browser. However I have some odd behaviour and I don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

The index.php has the line:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

and then within the codeigniter application folder there is a development folder which has a config.php. This has the base_url set which is currently set to point at the dev server ("http://exampleDevServer")

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://exampleDevServer"';
```

I have changed this line so that it points to the xampp server on localhost, i.e.

```
$config['base_url'] = $config['base_url']   = 'http://127.0.0.1/';
```

When I press the run button it looks like it breifly goes to that server then straight away gets redirected to http://exampleDevServer.

There is a .htaccess file which has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://exampleDevServer$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampleDevServer/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried with both rewrite on and off with no effect.

What I would like to happen is that when I am developing locally it is run from the xampp server and then I can change the define to production (or whatever) and then it points to the write place. What do I need to change in the above to fix this?

Comment: Trace through it with xdebug...

Comment: did you check this `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: Comment out 2 lines below `RewriteEngine On` line, clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: I think this might have been a caching issue in Firefox. I was getting different results with both localhost and 127.0.0.1. I reset my cache and reset all my changes and now I get a blank screen. I think this is actually progress and a different issue. I know have a clear cache button installed on firefox.

Comment: O, I also followed the advice of @anubhava in terms of comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this comes down to http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ - Yes. WIth Firefox automatically directing me to something it thought localhost should be going to, in this case the dev server instead of my local server.

I also changed my htaccess file as suggested in the comments to the below.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://exampleDevServer$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampleDevServer/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your confi file
File : **application/config/config.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$host = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'CLI';
$config['local_ip'] = array('localhost','127.0.0.1');

if($host != 'CLI') {
    if(in_array($host,$config['local_ip'])) {
        $config['base_url'] = '';
    } else {
        $config['base_url'] = 'YOUR_LIVE_URL';
    }
} else {
    if(CLI_ENVIRONMENT == 'local') {
        $config['base_url'] = '';
    } else {
        $config['base_url'] = 'YOUR_LIVE_URL';
    }
}
?>
```